# What were Category III threats?

Tags: plot-explanation, person-of-interest

Immediately after Control was ordered to shut down the program in *Person of Interest*, she could be seen sadly looking at a folder labeled "Category IV - threats relevant to national security."

What were the first 3 kinds of threats? Didn't the Machine just sort people into Relevant and Irrelevant categories? Also, as I understood it, the government was never even forwarded the Irrelevant list because it would look too suspicious if they suddenly started anticipating so many crimes, so shouldn't there only be one category from the government's perspective?

Comment: @Paulie_D This doesn't seem to be asking for explaining a plot point at all.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Not a plot explanation so much as why the folder said that, given that there appear to only be 2 categories (Relevant and Irrelevant) referenced in the show, and the Irrelevant list wasn't even forwarded to the government at all.